# strip a regex character match from a string

Tags: regex

I would like to strip specific character (the ampersand) match from any position on a string. An example of strings are;

```
&Discounts
Dis&counts
Discounts&
& Discounts
Discounts &
&amp;
```

I use the regex `&(?=\s|[a-zA-Z1-9])` but it can only match the ampersand at the beginning and the middle of the string. How can I also match if the ampersand is at the end of the string. And should be able to exclude match `&amp;`. Modified my regex to `&(?=\s|[^amp;])`. It was able to exclude the string `&amp;` but still not able to match the ampersand at the end of the string.

Comment: Simple regex such as `&amp;|&` will do it. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HfhQv/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to catch

```
[&](?!amp;)
```

and replace by empty

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/JSTpKG/4)

Comment: @Dren, is that what you want ? strip all & which is not followed by amp; ? if yes then my updated answer will work